# Inline code and short verb with minted

Tags: listings, verbatim, minted

I it possible to use minted for inline code and to add a short verb sing for minted? Like `\lstMakeShortInline|` in `listings.sty`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
   \newminted{tex}{}
   \newmint[ltx]{tex}{}

\begin{document}
Normal Text \ltx|\inline \Verb \not \inline|
\begin{texcode}
\Display \verbatim
\end{texcode}
Normal Text %|\not \working|
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`minted` supports this since v2.0 (on CTAN since 2015/01/31):

[image: inline code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
  You can use \mintinline{latex}{\mintinline{latex}{your $code$ goes here}} of
  the minted~2 package to highlight source code inline. If you already use
  \mintinline{latex}{\usepackage{minted}}
\end{document}
```

---

It is also possible to add a short verb sign:

from the [Dokumentation](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/releases/download/v2.0-alpha2/minted.pdf):

> `\newmintinline['macro name']{'language'}{'options'}`. If a
>   'macro name' is not specified, then the created macro is called `\'language'inline`
>
> [image: short inline]

Comment: Thanks that sounds good. Do you know if something like `\lstMakeShortInline|` is available (or planned) too?

Comment: Now I do ... :)

Comment: Thanks but thats not really what I meant. In the above example a short verb would be like `X|my $foo = $bar;|X`, i.e. only delimited by the pipes …

Comment: @Tobi I intentionally didn’t build this into minted (and neither did Geoffrey, presumably for the same reason) because it’s incredibly bad design in my opinion. LaTeX already has too many “magic” (active) characters, no need to add even more. If anything, users of TeX should *disable* active characters and math delimiters in general code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Good thought :-) but reducing the number of typed characters is nice too :-)

Comment: @Tobi, I still not not understand what you meant by `X|my $foo = $bar;|X`. What is X? It is the letter X? Can you show a real usage example?

Comment: @user : The `X` is just a normal text character as in my example. @Tobi wanted to be able surround their code by just  `|` and `|` instead of `\perlinline/` and `/`. or (using the `macro name` argument) `\p/` and `/` . (saving two keystrokes for every codeblock)

Comment: Exactly …, thanks Jan!

Answer (score 13):

So far there is no support for inline code since I (mistakenly, in hindsight) deemed this not important.

If I find some time to work on the next release, support for this may be added (and will probably break backwards compatibility). In the meantime, [somebody has posted a patch](http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=15) (be sure to read all the comments!) to make the `\mint` command inline. You may want to play with that.

Comment: Thank you. I read it and decided to use `listings` for inline and `mint` for displayed code. I accept your answer but I still hope that there is a official solution in a future version :-)

Comment: How do I install a patch? Im running OS X 10.6.

Comment: Hi Konrad, I also read that *Allow inline code* thread but that was old stuff and I'm not sure if the solution sketched there still applies. pygments seems also to be stuck in 2008 with version 1.4