# How to insert StackExchange style code?

Tags: pdftex

I want to highlight some code~ish thing in a report like this:

blahblahblah...Then you should use `./runprog` to start up the program etc etc...

How can I do this?

Comment: Of course you can just use `\veb{foo}`. Packages like [`listings`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) and [`minted`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) have inline versions `\lstinline` and `\mintinline`. A general overview can be found in http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/verbatim.html and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings. See also [Should I use \lstinline for the language keywords embedded in text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205362/35864) and [Inline code and short verb with minted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45756/35864).

Comment: Good sources to learn more thank you!@moewe

Comment: @moewe I wouldn't suggest `minted` for inline code. Its implementation is (was? up to1/2 years ago?) **really** buggy. It broke other much more important features.

Comment: You can try `\keys` or `\menu` from the package `menukeys` (although its original purpose is not a general “codish thing”).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `colorbox` command from [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \newcommand{\SEBox}[1]{\texttt{\colorbox{gray!14}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
     \SEBox{blahblah}
\end{document}
```

[image: monospaced example text on a gray background]

Comment: It works! Thank you! Could you kindly explain for me what is this command doing?

Comment: `\texttt` changes font to typewriter style; `\colorbox` changes the text background color to 10% transparent gray (gray!10).

Comment: What are [1] and {#1}?

Comment: `[1]` number of arguments passed to the command, and `#1` means use argument #1 here. For example, you can write `\newcommand{\SEBox}[2][gray!10]{\texttt{\colorbox{#2}{#1}}}` to be able to change the background color. Check this out: http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_19.html

Comment: BTW, it is typically recommended to wait for sometime before accepting answers, you might get better ones.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but your answer just works and is suitable for my use and most importantly is simplicity which I really appreciate as a LaTeX newbie.

Comment: @anetworknoobie You *ought* to read about command definitions etc. Just search things like "newcommand latex" on google and on this site and you'll find tons of resources about that. If you are using linux or mac be aware that you probably have `texdoc` installed. So if you want to learn about a certain package you can just launch from the terminal `texdoc package-name` to see its documentation (e.g. `texdoc mathtools`).