# How can I highlight software commands as code in text?

Tags: highlighting, code

I want to highlight some software commands as code in my text without any line break or any new paragraph for the code. Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: \verb!commandName!

Comment: The popular `listings` package has `\lstinline` (usage examples at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205362/35864). The also popular `minted` package has `\mintinline` (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45756/35864). If you don't need syntax highlighting there are `\verb|...|` for dangerous code that may contain special characters like `_` without breaking TeX or `\texttt{...}`, which may only contain safe text (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790/35864)